# Passing State as Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, counter

**EDITED**

So I have a Counter button component which I am rendering in my App. My App contains the state for the counter but how do I pass it as props to the Counter component? At the moment Counter has its own state but I want it to be using the state in App.

Also I am trying to make a universal counter button in a separate component which will increment/decrement the duplicate Counter buttons. But I have the same issue where I am not sure how to correclty pass the App's state as props into this universal button.

Universal Counter:

```
class UniversalCounter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const allCounter = [Counter]
    this.state = allCounter;
  }

  incrementCount() { 
    this.setState(prevState => ({ allCounter: prevState.allCounter + 1 }));
  }

  decrementCount() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ allCounter: prevState.allCounter - 1 }));
  }

  render() {
    let { allCounter } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>All Counters</h2>
        <button onClick={() => this.incrementCount(allCounter)}>increase all</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.decrementCount(allCounter)}>decrease all</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Counter Component:

```
class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { counter: 0 };
  }

  incrementCount() {
     this.setState(prevState => ({ counter: prevState.counter+ 1 }));
  }

  decrementCount() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ counter: prevState.counter- 1 }));
  }

  render() {
    let { counter} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Count: {counter}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => this.incrementCount(counter)}>+</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.decrementCount(counter)}>-</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { counter: 0 };
  }

  render() {
    let { counter } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Counter/>
        <Counter/>
        <Counter/>
        <UniversalCounter />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Move ***all*** the state into the parent. You don't want multiple sources of truth.

Comment: But if universal button is the only one with the counters in state, the other buttons won't work.

Comment: Could you show a snippet of how it looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loft state and handlers to closest common ancestor. `Counter` then becomes a "dumb" component.

[Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Counter.jsx

```
const Counter = ({ count, onIncrementClick, onDecrementClick }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Count: {count}</h2>
    <button type="button" onClick={onIncrementClick}>
      +
    </button>
    <button type="button" onClick={onDecrementClick}>
      -
    </button>
  </div>
);
```

UniversalCounter.jsx

```
const UniversalCounter = () => {
  const [counters, setCounters] = useState([0, 0, 0]);

  const incrementCount = (index, c) => () =>
    setCounters(counts =>
      counts.map((count, i) => (index === i ? count + c : count))
    );

  const incrementCountAll = c => () =>
    setCounters(counts => counts.map((count, i) => count + c));

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>All Counters</h2>
      {counters.map((count, i) => (
        <Counter
          key={i}
          count={count}
          onIncrementClick={incrementCount(i, 1)}
          onDecrementClick={incrementCount(i, -1)}
        />
      ))}

      <button type="button" onClick={incrementCountAll(1)}>
        Increase All
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={incrementCountAll(-1)}>
        Decrease All
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit multiple counters common state]

If (*for some not DRY reason at all*) wanted to render each Counter individually:

```
return (
  <div>
    <h2>All Counters</h2>

    <Counter
      count={counters[0]}
      onIncrementClick={incrementCount(0, 1)}
      onDecrementClick={incrementCount(0, -1)}
    />
    <Counter
      count={counters[1]}
      onIncrementClick={incrementCount(1, 1)}
      onDecrementClick={incrementCount(1, -1)}
    />
    <Counter
      count={counters[2]}
      onIncrementClick={incrementCount(2, 1)}
      onDecrementClick={incrementCount(2, -1)}
    />

    <button type="button" onClick={incrementCountAll(1)}>
      Increase All
    </button>
    <button type="button" onClick={incrementCountAll(-1)}>
      Decrease All
    </button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to retain keep the counter components 'stateful' instead of 'stateless' or 'dumb' like you said? In my App.js i have the other counters being imported/called and wish to keep it like that, in addition to having the universal counter. I will add my App to the OP.

Comment: Not really, you still want only a single source of truth for each individual counter, and the issue is the update functions for each counter are internal to them, so there's no good way to expose them out to components at or above the component in the tree. The alternative to lofting state & behavior to an ancestor is to use global state (react context, redux, etc..), but the concept is the same, each "counter" component is connected to a "piece of state" that it can act upon, and some "ultimate counter" can act on all of them. Redux would handle this with dispatched actions for example.

Comment: Ok I modified my code to have just one counter component and render it 3 times in App, where the state will be. How would it look like passing the state as props to the Counter? And can the universal button be in a separate component with state being passed as props?

Comment: With the state in `App.js` then you should also move the update functions there. Pass state to the counters, pass the handlers to both the counters and the universal button. https://codesandbox.io/embed/multiple-counters-common-state-to3hh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark

Comment: Is it possible to pass state as props to the counters and not use setState? And have the App's render block just contain the counter 3 tunes and universal counter?

Comment: @JabbatheHutt As I understand your question to be, yes, in the sandbox I linked in my previous comment. `App.js` has the state and handlers, passes counter state and individual handler to each `Counter`, and the universal handler to the universal counter.

Comment: I meant that in my App's return block should only contain the <Counter/> 3 times or so and <Universal/> and how to pass the state as props to the Counter and Universal components rather then using useState*.

Comment: Here you can see how App's return is: https://codesandbox.io/embed/elastic-framework-dnuzg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark  And App's state should be passed down as props to Counter.

Comment: @JabbatheHutt My demo just happens to be a functional component, but state works (*nearly*) the same way. Are you simply asking how to do this with a class-based component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210912/discussion-between-jabba-the-hutt-and-drew-reese).

Comment: Class-based `App.js` https://codesandbox.io/embed/reverent-bash-jvl3l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Is it possible to have the counters pass the state and handlers in the return block multiple times without mapping and having it all done in one?

Comment: @JabbatheHutt Added to answer if you really want to see how it'd be done like that.

Comment: Does incrementCount func need changing? Normal counters don't work but universal does.        https://codesandbox.io/embed/laughing-sara-hvnq2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @JabbatheHutt In your sandbox, `Count` takes `incrementCount` and `decrementCount` as props, but you're passing `onIncrementClick` and `onDecrementClick` to them in `App.js`.